# 404 when retrieving stylesheets

Tags: html, css

There are a number of external stylesheets included in [this webpage](http://ic-aviation.com/). For some strange reason, some of them are retrieved successfully, e.g.

- responsive.css
- theme.css

but others return a 404 when the browser tries to download them, e.g.

- bootstrap.css
- font-awesome.css
- fonts.css

I've logged into the server and checked that all the above CSS files are present and have the same permissions. When I run the site locally, all the CSS files load successfully.

Comment: I'm getting a 200 status code on every CSS loaded. What's your browser?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome / W7

Comment: It's all good for me, using chrome.

Comment: Works fine with firefox and chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Used Chrome to get to these... [**bootstrap.css**](http://ic-aviation.com/stylesheets/bootstrap.css),  [**font-awesome.css**](http://ic-aviation.com/stylesheets/font-awesome.css), and [**fonts.css**](http://ic-aviation.com/stylesheets/fonts.css)  Just don't forget that font-awesome pulls other font files that you'll have to play around with until you get the sheet's location correct.

Comment: Did you try other browsers, other computers?

Answer (score 1):

They are working just fine for me. delete your cache and such and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

It's working smooth here, I can see all of those CSS files in my browser. Try again after clearing the browser cache, hope it will work then.